# Find Min and Max value in table between given variable in C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following database table:

```
COL-A COL-B
1     $200
2     $100
4     $50
5     $40
```

What i need to do is if i have the value **1.5**, i need to find the two numbers that fall between it, so that would be **1** and **2**.

I need the values to input into a linear equation for a pricing calculator that i am working on.

The values may not always be the same, so it could even be like so:

```
COL-A COL-B
    1     $200
    6     $100
    11     $50
    22     $40
```

If i had **9**, i would then to return both **6** and **11** as **9** falls between those two values, etc etc

Visualising this i would need them put into seperate variables:

```
double Min = the_lowest_value;
double Max = the_highest_value;
```

I am using EF to do this, so it would need to be in LINQ.

Comment: Using EF doens't require you to use Linq for everything.  It might be easier (depending on data volumes) to retrieve the whole table content and then find the correct value yourself.  Also: is the data in your table sorted?

Comment: What if you pick a value that is in the table?  For example, what values should `6` return in the second table?

Comment: It wont be a big table, so data volume wouldn't be a problem. Initially the data would be ordered, but on the off chance that it isn't i can sort it before hand.

Comment: Use Max where a < value Min where a > value

Comment: It will do a lookup first to see if the value is in the table, if not, it needs to know what is.
If the value is lower than the MIN value, for eg 1 or the value is higher than the MAX value 22, it won't need to be processed through the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve it in one query, but again, the OP must ensure the given value is between two existing values.

```
using (var context = new YourContext()) {
    var val = 15;
    var query2 = context.Table
        .GroupBy(
            x => new {
                IsGreaterThan = x.Column > val,
                IsLessThan = x.Column < val
            },
            (key, data) => new { key = key, data = data.Select(x => x.Column) }
        )
        .Select(x => x.key.IsGreaterThan ? x.data.Min() : x.data.Max())
        .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("First value larger than {0} = {1}", val, query2[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("First value smaller than {0} = {1}", val, query2[1]);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution that requires 2 DB requests:

```
double the_lowest_value = Ctx.YourEntities
        .Where(z => z.ColA <= 9)
        .OrderByDesc(z => z.ColA)
        .Select(z => z.ColA)
        .First();

double the_highest_value = Ctx.YourEntities
        .Where(z => z.ColA >= 9)
        .OrderBy(z => z.ColA)
        .Select(z => z.ColA)
        .First();
```

Do note that if your value (`9` in the above example) is in your table, both variables will have the same value (`9`).

---

EDIT: As Slauma noticed, this would crash (i.e. throw an `InvalidOperationException` exception) if the specified value is lower/greater than any value of `ColA`, as `First()` requires at least one element in the returned sequence. You could use `FirstOrDefault()` to return the default `double` value if the sequence is empty:

For positive values:

As `default(double)` is `0.0`, the value would be OK for `the_lowest_value` (if the specified input value is `0.5` with your second example).
For `the_highest_value`, you could test after the DB query that's it's actually greater or equal than the specified input value. If it's not the case, you'll know the value you specified was greater than every value of the `ColA` column.

Comment: @Slauma true, the use of First() requires the query to return at least one value, so the OP must be sure lowest/highest values exist in DB for the specified input value.

Comment: Yes, or use nullable results, like: `double? the_lowest_value = ...Select(z => (double?)z.ColA).FirstOrDefault()`. Result will be `null` then if input value is lower than the lowest value in DB (the same for the highest value).

Comment: @Slauma I just edited the question and added information about `FirstOrDefault()` :) Your `(double?)z.ColA` cast is actually a very good idea. This would solve the issue with negative values, as `default(double?)` is `null`, so with that we're sure it's not a DB value (that `default(double)` (0.0) could be).